# What brand of tupperware-style (kitchen storage containers) are the easiest to clean?

Tags: storage-method, storage

I'm trying my best to keep this from being too opinionated, but I won't be offended if this gets closed.

I'm looking for a new set of storage containers and while there are a lot of factors that would weigh my choice (nesting/stacking, ecology, etc), the most critical would be ease of cleaning.

Factors to consider:

- **Materials**, and how prone they are to stain, scratch or get food stuck
  on
- **Texture and Corrugation**. I hate, **HATE**, the embossed brand names
  on my current cheap set. It's like they're specifically designed to
  capture scraps in them that are a pain to wash out!

Please include in your answer available brands that are a good fit for the above.

Comment: This is pretty opinion based... it's also a bit unclear what you mean by "kitchen storage containers"... there are about 3-4 vastly different products that could go by this name. Do you have a particular brand or two as examples? Are you talking about permanent ones or semi-reusable?

Comment: I didn't put a brand because I am looking for a brand that exemplifies the criteria. I figured "kitchen storage containers" was specific enough for what I call 'tupperware'. I didn't want to use that since it's a brand name. What would you suggest?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with stating product names if it helps us understand what you mean. "Tupperware" is very different in purpose and reusability than "Gladware"... and both are more for storing prepared foods than canisters like Oxo's POP containers, which are generally for ingredients.

Comment: Wait a sec... so you don't want to talk about brands but you want us to list brands? You're willing to add that to your question but you're not willing to even explain what types of containers you're looking for or what their purpose is?

Comment: @Catija Okay! I've been cajoled before about wording things properly. I'll edit it!

Comment: @HighlandRat I believe Catija wasn't suggesting asking for brand recommendations, she was suggesting asking for examples of products (or brands) that are the general type of container you're looking for.

Comment: @Catija I saw his question first. I can only do one thing at a time!

Comment: @Jefromi that is correct. Requesting brand recommendations would be specifically off topic as it is across the network.

Comment: @Catija I don't understand, what do you mean by off-topic? Am I breaking a rule? Should I remove the question?

Comment: The part of your question about brands is indeed off topic. The part about "how to choose" can probably be made to work, but it can use some editing. For example, asking about the corrugations is impossible to answer without mentioning brands. The "which material is easier to clean" sounds like a good question, but you will have to narrow it down - an unglazed clay amphora is easy to clean if you store wheat in it and impossible to restore to the original condition if you store olive oil in it. And I intentionally picked an unlikely example (clay amphora) to remind you that (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) that your current question covers any possible container for any possible purpose of storage of any possible food. I think that, to become answerable, you have to narrow it down, saying which foods you intend to store, under what conditions, for how long, in what sizes, etc.

Comment: Also: what cleaning methods are available to you (hand washing, dishwasher?)

Comment: Unfortunately corrugation is the crux of the question for me. I don't think this is a good place for this question. Thank you for your input, I'll use your suggestions when asking on another site. - Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Glass containers will be the best one to use for liquid and or dry goods that can stain (some spices...)

Either mason jar type of containers or jars with clamp lids; both type can have replaceable lids or seals.

The upside of glass is that it is inert and will clean up easily.
The downside of glass is that they break more easily than plastic.

Plastic containers are good for dry goods (rice, grains, pastas...); they wear down in the long run, but good quality ones will be good for years if taking good care of them.

The downside of plastic is that it can take up odor of what it contains and can stain easily (depending on the plastic quality).
The upside is that they are cheap, and will not break that easily.

Comment: This is great information in terms of materials! Can you offer any suggestions for corrugation? ie: brands that avoid putting unnecessary grooves in lids that catch food. I'll edit my question.

Comment: don't know about that, I assume you have to shop around to find something you like (I don't think it really matters IMO)

Comment: I like reuse and not wasting, so for me jars are a great option when appropriate.  Most store bought items in jars are not usable for canning, though some brands have gone to using straight canning jars so you can, and the lids are never reusable due to modern rules and regs, for canning, but they certainly can be used for storage.